# Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:explicitly_shared'. on self hosted action

Tags: metadata, facebook-opengraph

The explicitly_shared parameter is not working on the action I've built and therefore the stories are not appearing on the users' timelines.  An example of the URL scraped is: http://www.lunker.com/posts/tdscA

When I run this through the opengraph debugger, it presents the following error: "Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:explicitly_shared'."  Here's the metadata it sees:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="205936312871520" />
    <meta property="fb:explicitly_shared" content="true" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="catchmylunker:lunker" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Lunker Photo" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.amazonaws.com/lunker_production/fish_photos/original/ce85a18aa54fe476b7cb3e909ce4f05f3e7adab7.JPG?1369326898" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.lunker.com/posts/tdscA" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    <meta property="og:determiner" content="a" />
```

What could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the reason for this problem was that my application needed to be resubmitted for approval in order for the explicitly_shared directive to function. We resubmitted it for the review process and it was approved, so it now works.